# How can I get a primary key from url, using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have an application on django, and I want to add it opportunities jquery.
I want to delete a row from the table. To delete the value from the database, I should find a primary key.

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" id="name" data-type="text" data-pk="31" data-url='/handbook/customers/31/change/' data-title="Enter value">Intel</a></td>
    <td>
        <p><a class="btn-danger" role="button" href='/handbook/customers/31/delete/'>Delete</a></p>
    </td>        
</tr>
```

jquery:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function()
{
    $('.btn-danger').click(function()
    {
        var result = window.confirm('Warning! Are you sure?');
        if (result == true)
        {                
            // I want to receive a primary key from url here (31 in example)          
        }    
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```
var primaryKey = $('#name').attr('data-pk');
```

or **[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**:

```
var primaryKey = $('#name').data('pk');
```

---

Edit: Based on your comment, you can do:

```
$('.btn-danger').click(function()
{
    var result = window.confirm('Warning! Are you sure?');
    if (result == true)
    {                
        var primaryKey = $(this).closest('td').prev().find('a').attr('data-pk');           
    }    
});
```

Side note: since `id` is unique, you need to use class instead for your anchors, so change `id="name"` to `class="name"`:

```
<td><a href="#" class="name" data-type="text" data-pk="31" data-url='/handbook/customers/31/change/' data-title="Enter value">Intel</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pick the primary key from url and for that you can try this

```
$( document ).ready(function()
{
    $('.btn-danger').click(function(e)
    {

        var result = window.confirm('Warning! Are you sure?');
        if (result == true)
        {                

            var t= $(this).attr('href');
            var rem = '/handbook/customers/';
            var rem2 ='/delete/';
            var result = t.split(rem).join('');
            var result2 = result.split(rem2).join('');


            alert(result2);
            // I want to receive a primary key from url here (31 in example)          
        }    
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div style="display:none;">
            <input type="text" id="id_pk" value="{{receivepo.receive_po_id}}">
          </div>
```

where receivepo is object name it must be in small latters(my object name is ReceicePo) and receive_po_id is primary key
and jquery

```
var primaryKey = $("#id_pk").val();
```